# Can I deploy a war in Glassfish 3.1.1 from any GF plugin for Eclipse into a virtual server?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, glassfish, virtual-server

I currently export war files and deploy them with GFish console. I wonder if I can directly deploy into Glassfish 3.1.1 using one of multiple GFish adapters for Eclipse. These work fine when doing a simple deploy on a directory context root, but I can't make them deploy as / (root) into a specific virtual server. Eveery one of my apps runs in its own virtual server and all of them have / as context root.
I've also been looking at glassfish-web.xml, which allows setting context-root, but can't find how to specify which virtual server a war should install.
Last: I've also checked the default war for a virtual server, but that makes GFish mix all virtual servers and try to deploy the war multiple times.

Thanks for any ideas or procedures for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The plugins do not support all the 'asadmin deploy' options.  There has not been a measurable demand for the feature from a customer.